# Adding m2m data: invalid literal for int() with base 10

Tags: python, django

I have a many-to-many relationship from my `Profile` model to my `Skills` model. If I try to clear and add new skills to a profile, I get `invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'Python'` (Python is the first skill to get processed).

I'm not sure what to do, as I'm 100% sure I'm passing model instances to `user.profile.skills.add()`.

```
skills = ['Python', 'PHP', 'back-end', 'CSS', 'MYSQL']
skills_to_add = []
for s in skills:
    try:
        skill = Skill.objects.get(name__iexact=s)
    except Skill.DoesNotExist:
        skill = Skill()
        skill.name = s
        skill.save()
    except Skill.MultipleObjectsReturned:
        print "Duplicate skill found: " + s
        continue

    skills_to_add.append(skill)

if len(skills_to_add):
    user.profile.skills.clear()
    user.profile.skills.add(*skills)
```

Comment: Which line raises the error?

Comment: The last one, `user.profile.skills.add(*skills)`. Looks like it doesn't like receiving lists as params. I've tried sending the pointer to a `QuerySet` and it strangely worked.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's just a simple debugging error (won't be of value for future visitors). Can't delete it because it already has answers.

Comment: @EduardLuca I dont think you should close this question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You shouldn't add to `user.profile.skills` a list of strings, you should add the list of  `Skill` objects.

In other words, use `skills_to_add` instead of `skills`

Comment: LE: Oh, I see what you mean. I sent the wrong variable to `.add`. Wanted to send `skills_to_add` instead of `skills`. Since this is a simple debugging error, I should delete the question.

Answer (score 0):

```
skills = ['Python', 'PHP', 'back-end', 'CSS', 'MYSQL']
for s in skills:
    try:
        skill = Skill.objects.get(name__iexact=s)
    except Skill.DoesNotExist:
        skill = Skill()
        skill.name = s
        skill.save()

    except Skill.MultipleObjectsReturned:
        print "Duplicate skill found: " + s
        continue

    skills_to_add.append(skill)

if len(skills_to_add):
    user.profile.skills.clear()
    profile = Profile.objects.get(user_id=user.id)
    for obj in skills_to_add:
        profile.skills.add(obj)
    profile.save()
```

`skills` is a field m2m in your Profile model

```
...
skills = models.ManyToManyField(Skill,...)
...
```

Comment: While this works, I want to clear the list of skills a user has, but only if there are new skills I can add for him. That's why I wanted to add the skills all at the end.